# Difference between двигается and движется

Tags: глаголы

While studying Russian, I encountered two words which both seem to translate to '(he/she/it) moves' or '(he/she/it) is moving': двигается and движется. Some Internet research (e.g. [this page](http://difficulties.academic.ru/44) which I can barely read) showed me that they're both conjugations of двигаться.

Is there any difference between them at all? If yes, in which situations should I prefer one over the other? And are there more words with a similar characteristic?

Comment: I can barely tell the difference. But if you want a rule, then I may propose the following: if it is a man or animal moving on its own - use двигается; if it is an inanimate or abstract thing - use движется; if something is moving, but not changing its position at large - again use двигается.

Comment: A big discussion of this tricky question in Russian can be found here: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?bid=25&tid=19619&hl=%e4%e2%e8%e6%e5%f2%f1%ff My personal opinions and suggestions are under nick Areyou.

Comment: Движется often is about moving in a special direction, you should use it with vehicles, for example. Двигается means "is in motion", like что-то двигается в темноте (something is moving in the dark). But don't worry, everybody will understand you even if you misuse the verb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb двигаться belongs to the group of избыточные глаголы. They have parallel forms in the present tense, in the imperative, and participles and деепричастия. These forms can differ stylistically and in meaning. 
The verb двигаться has got the following meanings.

1. Находиться в движении, перемещаться, направляться. –To be on the move, in the process of moving. Both forms are used.

> На Москву движется /двигается ураган. Нефтяное пятно движется/двигается  в сторону Испании.
>    В Японское море со скоростью 45 метров в секунду движется тайфун «Чатаан» 
>   Мы движемся / двигаемся в ногу со временем 
>    Автомобиль движется / двигается (= перемещается, передвигается) быстрее поезда.

2. Трогаться в путь, отправляться.To start movement, depart. Only двигается

> Пора двигаться в дорогу;
>   Машина двигается с места; Поезд двигается в путь

3. Шевелиться (слегка двигаться), изменять положение тела. To move a little, to change the position of the body. Both forms are used.

> Руки фокусника движутся / двигаются с необыкновенной быстротой.

4. Обладать способностью движения. To be able to move, can move. Only двигаются

> Ноги не двигаются (не может ступить, идти куда-нибудь); Экспериментальный поезд двигается без машиниста.

5. Перен. содействовать развитию чего-либо, побуждать, руководить. figurative (about non-material nouns) : To help development, to evoke, to lead. Only движется.

> Поиск ответа на этот сложнейший вопрос движет развитие современной биологии.  Научная мысль движется все быстрее.

When both forms are possible, двигается is preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed both words ***двигается*** and ***движется*** have the same meaning - "to move". Here is a rule of thumb that works 90% of the time:

**UPDATED:**

1. If you speak of body movement, or movement of body parts, you can use either form. However, they may differ in meaning. **Двигается** focuses on movement of body limbs. **Движется** focuses on movement in space.

> Танцор двигается как робот. / Танцор движется по площадке. *A dancer moves as a robot. / A dancer moves on podium.*
>
> Хищник бесшумно двигается. / Хищник движется по лесу. *A predator moves silently. / A predator moves through the woods*

2. If you speak of inanimate objects, use the form **движется**:

> Поезд движется к станции. *A train runs towards station.*
>
> Машины движутся по шоссе.  *Cars are running on a highway.*

Comment: _Медведь **движется** в берлоге_ is an impossible expression while it is OK to say _медведь движется в направлении от берлоги к ручью_. As for inanimate objects: **поршень двигается** внутри цилиндра is quite a typical expression (found in many books, etc.). The difference is about **type** of motion,

Comment: @Alex_ander yes, example with bear sounds strange to me.

Comment: The example with bear was wrong.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Обычно, чем больше у иона величина отношения заряда к массе, тем быстрее он двигается к электроду.Is one example enough?

Comment: Там, при перевале через Урал, поезд двигается медленно, надзор, вероятно, ослабеет, по мере того, как конвой к нам привыкнет, да и мы успеем подготовиться. [О. С. Минор. Это было давно...

Comment: @V.V. I'm not saying that one cannot, or should not use **двигается** with inanimate or abstract objects.  But someone learning the language (not a native speaker) needs a simple way to avoid making obvious mistakes. In both examples that you provided, one can use **движется**.

Comment: One can use both, why saying, use this, don't use that?

Comment: @V.V. personally your trains example sounds to me weird, as a "personal dialect". I'd say it is a fusion between non-focused plural(поезда двигаются, (all) trains move) and focused singular (наш поезд движется, the/this/our train moves). While they say in singular, but they do not minfd any particular train, they talk about generic rule of all the future trains, they say "a train" not "the train", and that is why they use the verb form, that here is more suited for plural. That being said, it is my gut feeling, and perhaps my "personal dialect" would sound equally weird to them.

Comment: "why saying, use this, don't use that?" because of "Если вы потерялись в магазине - встречайтесь в центре возле фонтана". The easy recipe is to be correct one if simplified, the corner cases and exceptions would come later for those, who would bother investing their time into it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the nuances listed above, the difference is, roughly, that ***двигается*** means 'to move at one's own position or place' and ***движется*** means 'to move as related to some other position or place'. See the above examples with ***медведь*** and also cf:

***Дело двигается с мёртвой точки.*** = emphasis on beginning of the action, the situation and its change;

***Дело движется с мёртвой точки.*** = emphasis on targeted goal of the action

Answer (score 2):

Двигается has a wider meaning. It may mean moving one's limbs or jerk, while движется means moving in a direction.

Thus:

Танк двигается means the tank is moving its turret, or somehow showing motion in another way.

Танк движется means the tank is driving.